Getting SSL_Verification error while using deep_translator module
I need to translate a sentence, I found out about this library, but I am getting this error of failed SSL certificate verification.
I am using company laptop; I need a way to ignore the ssl certificate verification if possible.
This is my code -

from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator

text = "Hi, I am arya"
translated = GoogleTranslator(source="auto", target="de").translate(text=text)
print(translated)

I could not find any solution for this particular problem.
I found some solution for related questions, but nothing is working.
Thanks in advance

Your code snippet works for me out of the box.
Hallo, ich bin Arya

As this does not seem to be an issue you are having with the translation library directly following the troubleshooting in a general ssl certificate verification post will likely be what you are looking for.
I ran this snippet using python 3.12.2 in a venv with only the minimum required dependencies.

requests (2.32.3)
urllib3 (2.2.1)
certifi (2024.2.2)
charset-normalizer (3.3.2)
idna (3.7)
soupsieve (2.5)
beautifulsoup4 (4.12.3)
deep-translator (1.11.4)

Out of date dependencies, especially requests or urllib, could be the culprits of the problems you are having.

It works on personal laptop, but I am using company problem so that's why it's not working. I am looking for a way to ignore the verification.

It is definitely not advisable to turn off SSL Cert checking as that would leave you susceptible to certain kinds of attacks like man in the middle. However if you are determined this is the way rather than trying the steps in the question i pointed you too the the requests module has the capability to disable that. For instructions see this post on disabling ssl verification
